# Getting ID's from checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to get the ID's from a load of checkboxes that are in rows that are printed out on a page using a while statement. Each row from the database has a checkbox next to it with the ID in the checkbox value.

Basically I want to do a update query on the checkbox-selected rows, using the ID.

The code for the checkboxes that I have used is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
```

Then when the code for the submit is:

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
     foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $id){
        echo "$id was checked! ";
     }
   }
?>
```

Just wanted to echo out the results to test that it works before putting it into a query. Trouble is...nothing happens. I just get a blank screen. No error or anything. Surely it should work, it looks right but I don't understand why it doesnt work.

Any help is most appreciated! :)

Comment: That should work. Check the generated HTML. Check the HTTP request made when you submit the form.

Comment: When you look at the source code with the checkboxes, did you saw that all the checkboxes has the ID in the value attribute? It's just to check from the basics..

Comment: Can you echo/var_dump the value of `$rows['id']` to ensure there is something filled in the `value`-attribute?

Comment: Yes the ID is being put into the value of the checkbox, I already checked.

Comment: Also tried echoing something after the submit code above which does echo...

Comment: Check if your form is transmitted via `post` (`<form method="post">`).

Comment: Yes it's going via post.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich You should probably try to be a little more thoughtful when tagging your questions.  You tagged it with `mysql`, but the fact that you are getting/storing your data from a database is completely irrelevant to the question which has to do with handling form data.

Comment: The $_POST is definately working as it's successfully posting through another value from a drop down box. I echoed it and it appears. It just doesn't seem to do the checkboxes...the ID's don't appear at all.

Comment: @Useless Code - It's related to mysql becuase the ID's the form is sending are being grabbed from a database.

Comment: So, if it was from some online booking system, you'd tagged it 'football'?

Comment: Are you sure that something isn't messing with `$_POST` between the code that is working and the code that isn't?  Perhaps an accidental assignment inside of a conditional statement?  I ran that loop on my own server and it worked (after replacing `<?` with `<?php` since my server doesn't have [short open-tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled).

Comment: It's fixed now. My hosting company had a script running that conflicted with the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested below code with one test.php file

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
     foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $id){
        echo "<br>$id was checked! ";
     }
}


?>

<form method="post" name="frm">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="1"> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="2"> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="3"> 3
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="4"> 4
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

please check if you are getting $rows['id'] properly. Things should work fine otherwise.

Thanks.